# Select a row in a listView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have a listView and have populated it with text using an arrayAdapter. What I want to do is click on a row of text in my list, once the row has been clicked on it will then bring me to another screen. The below code is in my java file

```
    ListView listView;
    String[] from = { "Electricity","Groceries","Rent","Loan","Entertainment" };

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.zone_list);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.bills, R.id.AllBills, from);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

I then styled it in xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/zone_list"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add something as such:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("data_to_pass", some_data); //If needed
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setOnItemClickListener`.

Try something like

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                ListEntry entry= (ListEntry) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, /*your new activity*/);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

you should add this after you set the adapter of the listview. Of course do the needed modifications.

Answer (score 1):

Use [public void setOnItemClickListener (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)) method of AdapterView class